# Create frame around group of objects

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a geometry node setup (screenshot attached) which I'm using for windows. I'm using mesh lines to control the number of windows for the width and height. Can someone help with adding a border around the composition, which would resize based on the number of windows (yellow line in 2nd screenshot)? Basically, I want to have an additional border only on the outside of the shape.

Thanks!

[image: node setup]

[image: desired result]

[image]

Comment: Bounding Box, Merge by Distance, Extrude, Delete > Top ... doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To scale frame easier you can set generated [geometry to center](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/270263/2214)

[image]

Here is one way of frame ...

[image]

Mixed ...

[image]
[image]

You would have to scale frame or reposition frame profile, like now frame partly covers windows.

Note: probably would be easier to start with a Grid mesh primitive and instance faces, than build it on arrayed line ... but it depend on your needs.