# How I can remove the right half of a geometry using a geometry node?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have the following geometry, and I only need the left half

[image]

To remove the right part I'm trying to use the `Mesh Boolean` node with a bounding box scaled by half to do a difference between them, but I get his result

[image]

What I'm doing wrong? I would have expect from this node setup to cut the Mesh 1 in half

Comment: I see you've got a solution, just a few thoughts on your initial setup: the left and right part are one object although the meshes are not connected, so there is one bounding box surrounding them both together. Scaling down on X by 50% will just make this box "thinner" in X direction towards its center, not just on one side, so the _Mesh Boolean_ would cut out the middle of the object by half of its overall width. Even if the obejcts were separate and you had separate bounding boxes, scaling them on X would also just make them thinner towards there center and make them move towards each other.

Comment: Now, I said this would usually make the _Mesh Boolean_ cut out the center of the object - however, it does not even do that. But if you look closely, there is this small "speech bubble" with the letter `i` in it, indicating there is some information about a problem. Hover your mouse over it so it can tell you what is wrong with your setup and why it is not cutting out the center (which is not what you want , but what I would expect from this setup). I would guess the object you plug in there is an instance and not a mesh object, then the _Mesh Boolean_ remains only showing the bounding box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the Plane X=0 divides your mesh into two halves, you can delete all points with X coordinate greater than 0. Here's an example with a mesh that consists of two cubes.

[image]

Comment: thank you, your solution is way faster than mine since with this you don't need to realize the instance. Could be also possible to move the origin to the center? After deleting the geometry the origin goes from the center to the right side

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/247900/how-to-set-the-origin-of-a-procedurally-created-mesh-in-geometry-nodes

Comment: Not even as a nitpick, just to spread the unintuitive conversion rule of scalars (floats) to booleans: The "Math: Greater Than" node is redundant there - that's exactly how the implied conversion works.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Oh neat. I assumed it was "non-zero".

Answer (score 2):

In the end I found this solution, but I wonder if there is still a better/simpler way of doing this

I basically used the bounding box of the geometry to create a selection that will clip the part that I don't want when used with the Intersect option of the Mesh boolean.

The bounding box was scaled in half and then moved to right so it's placed in the place I want not to be seen.

[image]